# Javascript: Get date string from raw date

Tags: javascript, date

I have another question on SO [Unable to read date cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602970/office-365-unable-to-read-date-cell). This question is related to last question but more generic. How to convert Raw date, which represents number of days since `1st Jan 1900`, to a javascript date type? [ Forget office365 ].

I have number of days elapsed since `1st Jan 1900`. How can I get the date from it. For ex: I need a date after `42216` days, since `1st Jan 1900`, How can I calculate that date?  Answer is : 31-Jul-2015.

Comment: somebody downvoted, please comment I will improve my question.

Comment: Not the downvoter but your question is not clear. You can edit and add more details as to what you are trying to achieve!

Comment: @RahulTripathi State your confusion.

Comment: Can you give example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: please show you approach and effort.

Comment: -all , made an update. Please comment if anything is not clear?

Comment: @Saif Instead, I am asking for your approach. moreover, not looking to reinvent the wheel(if wheel exists), a lib would help.

Comment: except  giving you the approach from scratch, i would like to give some suggestion or can try to help you out if you got stuck which i can't do   unless you make some effort or take any initiative.

Comment: @Saif Yes please, post your suggestion. That may help.

Comment: `i can't do unless you make some effort or take any initiative`

Comment: @Saif oh, but what is that effort or initiative?

Comment: its only downvoted, not closed, you should be happy, the topic is covered hundred times here and all over the internet, you didnt do any effort to check, and even though problem, is simple the question is messy and unclrear, I downvoted it too

Comment: I will delete it later.

Comment: the effort is you start searching google, you try to think any possible solution and you start writing code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
(function(){
  var date = new Date(1900,1,1);
  var dayCount = 42216;
  
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + dayCount)
  console.log(date);
})()
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess, this will get me going.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
start = "01/01/1900"
newDate = start.split("/");
x = new Date(newDate[2]+"/"+newDate[1]+"/"+newDate[0]);
var numberOfDaysToAdd = 42216;

x.setDate(x.getDate() + parseInt(numberOfDaysToAdd)); 

var dd = x.getDate();
var mm = x.getMonth() + 1;
var yyyy = x.getFullYear();

var format = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy;

alert(format);
```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4RZAa/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Hope it help:

```
var dateStart= new Date('1900-01-01');

var afterDay=42216;

var newDay=new Date(dateStart.getTime() + afterDay*24*60*60*1000);

alert(newDay);
```